# `pwd`, but omit first n directories

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed

`pwd` gives the full path of the current directory, for example:

```
/first/second/third/anotherdir/thefinaldirectory
```

How can I omit the first n, let's say three directories, so that only

```
/anotherdir/thefinaldirectory
```

is returned?

I guess this should be possible with `sed`?

Answer (score 2):

Bash has some built-in string manipulation:

```
echo "/${PWD#/*/*/*/}"
```

Comment: Note that `$PWD` is not always the same as the result from `pwd`. And also it appends `/` to the beginning of result if `$PWD` content can not be matched by pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cut` for this, e.g.:

```
pwd | cut -d/ -f 4-
```

prints splits the output of `pwd` by `/` and prints from the fourth field to the end.

In your case that would be:

```
echo "/first/second/third/anotherdir/thefinaldirectory" | cut -d/ -f 5-
```

Answer (score 1):

With any POSIX `sed`:

```
pwd | sed 's,\(/[^/]*\)\{3\},,'
```

or:

```
pwd | sed -E 's,(/[^/]*){3},,'
```

`-E` works with GNU and BSD sed, and will [become standard in near future](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528).